# Minor change to the "Provide Context to Links" subsection on the /how-to-answer page

Tags: discussion, help-center

On the /how-to-answer page, I think there should be a small change to the "provide context to links" subsection:

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always summarize or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

This adds the words "summarize or" before "quote". The previous wording seemed like quotes were required. Depending on the complexity of the resource, a summary of the contents should be more than sufficient, if it answers the question. It could also be easier to digest for readers who want more of an abstract before getting into the details.

Comment: "Quote" also leads people to think wholesale copy and paste is acceptable.